# Errors installing Capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qt, homebrew, capybara-webkit

I am trying to install the capybara-webkit gem and get the following error in OSX 10.9.4:

```
➜  hours git:(development) gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.2.0' 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Command 'qmake -spec macx-g++ ' not available

Makefile not found

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-webkit-1.2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/capybara-webkit-1.2.0/gem_make.out
```

So, researching that problem it seems like the solution is to run "brew install qt". When I run that I get the following:

```
➜  hours git:(development) brew install qt 
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
==> Downloading http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-everywhere-open

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Download failed: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5.tar.gz
```

I have checked and cannot find MacPorts or Fink anywhere on my Imac.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew has carried qt 4.8.6 since April. Please `brew update && brew upgrade` and try `brew install qt` again.